# C++ pointer to elements of memoryblock

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

consider the follow code:

```
byte *memblock = new byte[500];
byte **ptr_to_memblock  = &memblock;
memblock += 40;
ptr_to_memblock  = &memblock;
```

ptr_to_memblock will always hold the same value in the above example.
I guess that come from the fact that the address of memblock (with or without offset) will always return the address of the continuous memory block.

The problem with that is that I wanted to implement some sort of DynamicHeap class where you could allocate memory of arbitary size and free it in arbitary order. The class uses a memory block (like memblock above) which will be replaced by a bigger memory block once the memory block is full. The problem with that is that I need to keep track of all objects that use memory of the DynamicHeap class because once I allocate a bigger block to replace it with the old block I need to reassign all pointers that are used by my programs. I wanted to do this via pointers to the memory I return when my programs want to get memory from the DynamicHeap class. Unfortunately the pointer to the memory I return is always the pointer to the memory block I use internally.

Is there any way to get pointers of specific addresses within continuous memory blocks?

Any answer is appreciated.

[EDIT] Maybe this example will help to understand what my problem is:

```
//byte = typedef char
byte *memblock = new byte[sizeof(Object) * 2];

Object *myObject1 = new((Object*)memblock) Object;
Object *myObject2 = new((Object*)memblock + sizeof(Object)) Object;

Object **ptr_to_myObject1 = &myObject1;
Object **ptr_to_myObject2 = &myObject2; //will be the same as ptr_to_myObject1

byte *memblock2 = new byte[sizeof(Object) * 3];
memcpy(memblock2,memblock,sizeof(Object) *2);

*ptr_to_myObject1 = (Object*)memblock2;
*ptr_to_myObject2 = (Object*)memblock2 + sizeof(Object); //Won't work.

delete[] memblock;
memblock = NULL;
```

I can only reassign the pointer to myObject1 (as it is the same as address as memblock), but I cant reassign the pointer to myObject2 (as &myObject2 is the same as &myObject1 (which is the same as &memblock)).

Comment: you mean you want to use the same area of memory after you delete *memblock pointing to that area?

Comment: This is not true, 'as &myObject2 is the same as &myObject1'. Don't know how to say it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the address of the variable memblock, that never changes. I think you are confusing the address of a variable with the addresses of the allocated memory.

The way to get a pointer to a specific address inside the allocated memory is the way you are doing in the code above, `memblock + 40` is a pointer to the address 40 bytes inside the the allocated memory. But given what I think you are trying to do this isn't going to help.

One way to do this is to allocate *handles*, handles are pointers to pointers. When you allocate some memory you also allocate a handle from a separate place. You initialise the handle to point to the allocated memory `*handle = memblock + offset; return handle;`. Now when you resize the heap you can go though all the handles (which you've kept in a list somewhere) and reassign them `*handle = new_memblock + new_offset;`. The problem is that your programs have to deal with handles instead of pointers, which is awkward.

Comment: I'm doing exactly that. consider `Object* myObject = DynamicHeap->Allocate(sizeof(Object)); //where *myObject is memblock + 40` The problem is that I need to reassign these handles once the block's getting bigger. My current approach is to save the pointer of the address memblock + 40 (. As soon as a new memory block is allocated, I go through all those pointers and reassign them. Unfortunately is the pointer to the memblock (&memblock) the same as the pointer to memblock + 40 (&(memblock + 40)).

Comment: I think you have something confused. In your code `myObject` is not a handle it's a pointer. There is no such thing as the pointer of an address. There is no sensible way to reassign pointers in the program code. The only way do to this (assuming I'm understanding you right) is by returning handles from your allocation routine. `Object **myObject = DynamicHeap->Allocate(sizeof(Object))`, in this version `myObject` is a handle not a pointer.

Comment: I've just read your expanded code above. It works fine for me. This comment is wrong `//will be the same as ptr_to_myObject1`. The values of `ptr_to_myObject1` and `ptr_to_myObject2` are not the same, they are the addresses of two different variables so they cannot be the same. Just try printing them out if you don't believe me. It's clear the you have the address a pointer variable is pointing to and the address of that variable itself confused.

Answer (score 0):

ptr_to_memblock  = &memblock. Here you store the address of the variable memblock in the variable ptr_to_memblock. Memblock is a variable stored somewhere in memory at a specific adress which will never change.